# CSS different padding rule for Windows?

Tags: css, cross-platform

I have padding set the way I want on Windows at `2.8em` and it looks good. However it messes up the layout on Linux and Mac.

Apparently to correct the issue it needs to be `2.4em` on the non-Windows OS's. But at `2.4em` it looks ugly on Windows.

Is there a way that I can target the OS and set the padding to `2.8em` if Windows and `2.4em` if not?

Comment: Do you have a font size set? What does that look like? This is most likely a dpi issue. It may be possible to do this by parsing the user agent, extracting the OS from it, and serving customized style sheets, but it would be more feasible to fix the underlying problem instead

Comment: 'em' is based on font size. Windows, Linux, and Mac typically have different default fonts and even if they were all the same they use different rendering so they still wouldn't be exact. So what you're seeing is that it looks good with your particular setting. (Try zooming the text in or out and you'll see the padding change)

Comment: So should I be using `px` instead of `em` then?

Comment: If you need pixel perfect precision, yes. You *should* design your site in a flexible manner though so it looks good regardless of font and size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a reset stylesheet to try and normalise all browsers http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/